# Change the layout of Navigation bar on BigCommerce template

Tags: html, css, bigcommerce

I am trying to change the layout of the navigation bar of a big commerce templated (http://www.bigcommerce.com) website from,

> menu1 | menu2 | menu3 | menu4

to,

> menu1 | menu2 | menu3 | menu4
>
> menu1.1
>
> menu1.2

so when you hover over menu1 the sub-menus(1.1,1.2) will be displayed. Is this possible on BigCommerce?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another Big resource,

"Customizing Your Store's Design 101"
https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/1314/Customizing+Your+Store%27s+Design+101

Comment: Two things: (1) Why make another answer? Why not edit the answer you have? (2) Please include some content in the links to your answer, as links can become unavailable, so SO can be a place where the answer can be recorded.